# Starting virtualenv script rc local

Tags: python, linux, virtualenv, boot

I'm very newbie in this field and hope someone can help me.

So I have a backend project which I need to launch automatically when the computer switches on (I really don't care how, using systemd or rc.local, my boss told me rc.local, but I guess either will do). I just need to start a docker container, then start my virtualenv and then run the project.

So far I've tried this at `/etc/rc.local`

`docker start cassandratt #my docker container
sleep 20 #an ugly hack to give time for the container to start
cd /home/backend/
. venv/bin/activate
. /run.py`

It doesn't work, but the docker container starts, so I guess the problem is around virtualenv or python, I really don't know as I don't have any experience on this field.

Any idea on how I could accomplish it?

Thanks in advance

**Edit:**

Following Samer's guidance I tried creating a folder after activating the virtualenv and it created fine, so I suppore the problem is trying to execute run.py, perhaps loading the virtualenv's python?

`docker start cassandratt #my docker container
cd /home/backend/
. venv/bin/activate
mkdir test #folder created fine
. /run.py
mkdir test2 #folder not created`

Comment: give full paths to these executables/scripts. and run them with /path/to/activate and 'python /path/to/run.py'

Comment: Full path to the virtualenv is: /home/backend/venv/bin/activate. I tried it on a shell and I have permission denied

Comment: so thats your problem, allow permissions to execute 'activate'

Comment: I get the same denied permission from a root terminal. That shouldn't happen, should it?

Comment: Nope it shouldn't try 'chmod +x  /home/backend/venv/bin/activate' maybe the file isn't set to be an executable.

Comment: @SamerTufail I don't think that's the issue, as in order to activate the virtualenv "venv" I need to use . venv/bin/activate or source venv/bin/activate. The script in the post works fine in a normal terminal shell, I think I don't need to mark it as an executable as I can already activate venv. I just don't know how to make it work in rc.local :(

Comment: to call the script from rc.local provide permissions on the script using chmod +x and then call that script from rc.local - that should work if you can execute the script fine in a normal terminal.

Comment: I used chmod +x on activate file, changed the rc.local script to match absolute paths but still doesn't work :(

Comment: try to run the python script by adding 'python /path/to/run.py'

Comment: I can't, I need to use the virtualenv's python as I'm using flask and I need the project to be sandboxed (that's why I'm using virtualenv). If I put python before run.py it will try to execute the global Python which will result in an exception, as it won't recognize Flask. (Already tried it in terminal)

Comment: aah I see I missed that. can you export virtualenvs python environment variables and restore them after your env activates?

Comment: My boss gave me a hand, I'll answer in a minute :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, partially, the solution seems to set some variables instead of accesing them directly. At least this worked for me. Thanks Samer for giving us a big tip :)

```
HOME=/home/backend #the project path
docker start container
. $HOME/venv/bin/activate #activates the virtualenv of the project
/usr/bin/env python $HOME/run.py & #runs the run.py through virtualenv's python #and runs it in the background
exit 0
```

Comment: happy to help!.